# matplotlib versions >=3 does not include a find()

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am running a very simple Python script:

```
from tftb.generators import amgauss, fmlin
```

I get this error:

```
C:\Users\Anaconda3\envs\tf_gpu\lib\site-packages\tftb-0.0.1-py3.6.egg\tftb\processing\affine.py in <module>
     12 
     13 import numpy as np
---> 14 from matplotlib.mlab import find
     15 from scipy.signal import hilbert
     16 from scipy.optimize import brenth, newton

ImportError: cannot import name 'find'
```

I believe `find` is no longer in versions  >=3. How can I get around this without downgrading Matplotlib?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The code of the `matplotlib.mlab.find` function was literally

```
import numpy as np

def find(condition):
    res, = np.nonzero(np.ravel(condition))
    return res
```

You may replace any occurance with that function.