# What did pylab.find() do while it was still existing?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have an inherited code where there's a line using `pylab.find()`:

```py
import numpy
import pylab
xsnp['q'] = numpy.array([xsnp['ff'][pylab.find(xsnp['T']==x), 0] for x in xsnp['xyz']]).reshape(N,)
```

(`xsnp` is a dict of Numpy arrays).

However, this method does not seem to be available anymore as the line above causes a

```
AttributeError: module 'pylab' has no attribute 'find'
```

I could not find it using Google anywhere. Numpy doesn't seem to have a `find()` function and Pylab is a godawful mess of a ton of star-import from different modules, so I have no idea where to look.

What was `pylab.find()`, and what could I replace it with?

Comment: That might have been `matplotlib.mlab.find`, which was a [pretty simple function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57100894/matplotlib-versions-3-does-not-inlclude-a-find#57100894). (Looks like wjandrea just found the same thing.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Matplotlib **API Changes for 3.1.0**:

> ### [`pylab` removals](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/prev_api_changes/api_changes_3.1.0.html#pylab-removals)
>
> Lots of code inside the [`matplotlib.mlab`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/mlab_api.html#module-matplotlib.mlab) module which was deprecated in Matplotlib 2.2 has been removed. This means the following functions are no longer available in the [`pylab`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/index.html#module-pylab) module:
>
> ...
>
> - `find` (use `np.nonzero(np.ravel(condition))` instead)

Note, to replicate the behavior of `find`, you will need to extract the first element of the tuple returned by `np.nonzero(np.ravel(condition))`.

(For reference, I found this by searching for `pylab.find` in the Matplotlib documentation after reading the below question.)

Related question: [matplotlib versions >=3 does not include a find()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57100894/matplotlib-versions-3-does-not-include-a-find)